# Rewrite from Subdirectory 1 in root to Subdirectory 2 in root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have:

```
www/Directory1
www/Directory2
```

I have 1 subdomain in 2 domains:

```
test.domainA.com
test.domainB.net
```

All subdomains redirects to **www/Directory1**.
(This is auto redirect from custom hosting Panel)...

I want create a rewrite to redirect the **test.domainB.net** to **www/Directory2**.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainB.net$
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_HOST}/Directory2/$1 [R]
```

Comment: I had to check with the hosting of the problems, but I appreciate the help. :)